# What is this plant with two types of leaves and small pinkish-white flowers?

Tags: identification, flowers

[image][image]

Plant purchased as a hanging basket, has both variegated and solid green leaves, has upright growth, but also has two or three vine like stems. Flowers are VERY delicate white some with a delicate pink throat like.

Purchased at a nursery that told me the name of this plant was "Snow on the Mountain."  After researching I am quite sure this is incorrect. However I cannot find a picture on the Internet to help in identifying it. 
Can anyone help?

Comment: Welcome to the site Billie! You may be right. It doesn't look at all like my Snow on the Mountain, although I don't know if there are different types. Can you post some more pictures, specifically of the stems? Are you sure there's only one type of plant in the pot? Thanks!

Comment: I am sure only one plant in pot. New to this site and can't figure out how to add another picture. Any help on that would be appreciated!

Comment: Glad to help! Under the question, press on the word "edit." It will open the box where you wrote your question. (You can press on this [edit] if it's easier.) I've put some space above your text. Put your cursor there, then click on the little icon that looks like a picture and upload more pictures the way you did the first one. There's also a little question mark on the top right of the question box which leads to formatting help.  If you're still confused, no problem, just leave another note. I'll check back later in the day (it's 1am in the USA).

Comment: 'Snow on the Mountain' is a common name applied to many plants, so its not useful in terms of ID - no Latin name anywhere on the tag I suppose? Otherwise, more pics would be very useful to determine whether there's more than one plant in the pot...

Answer (score 5):

I did some research, having recognised that the white and pink parts on this plant aren't flowers, they're actually leaves - they should change colour later as they mature, initially to dappled white and green, then probably to plain green. I thought it might be one of the new Euonymus varieties along the lines of 'Pierrolino', but it's not - its actually Alternanthera ficoidea 'Snow on the Mountain', the last part being its varietal name rather than a common name. Sometimes commonly known as Parrot Plant or Calico plant, or even Joseph's Coat, though that particular common name refers to the one with variegated reddish tones. It prefers full sun to partial shade, and grows to about 18 inches tall. It's a tropical plant, or an indoor perennial, so quite tender.

Comment: Bamboo, you are amazing...looked this up and I agree...

Comment: @stormy not that amazing, or I'd be wealthy!

Comment: Amazing is totally separate from wealthy...grin!  Your plant sense and knowledge ARE AMAZING.

Answer (score 0):

this plant is definitely Alternathera Ficoidea "snow on the mountain".  My husband's 100 year old grandmother grew it for many years and last winter, it died.  I am desperately trying to replace it for her 101st birthday!!!.  If you know any place i can get it, I would be so grateful.
Michelle